# How do I find GEKKO application success status?

Tags: python, gekko

I am running `m.solve()` in a `try .. except` construct to elegantly handle any exceptions raised by the solver due to maximum iterations or convergence to an infeasibility but want to interrogate APPINFO and  APPSTATUS to determine if a solution was found.  I was surprised to see that I always seem to get `APPINFO=0` and `APPSTATUS=1` even though the the solver reports that a solutions was not found.

What am I missing in my interpretation of the document on APPINFO and APPSTATUS?

Piece of code to reproduce error.

```
from gekko import GEKKO

m=GEKKO(remote=False)

m.x=m.Var()
m.y=m.Var()

m.total=m.Intermediate(m.x+m.y)

m.Equation(m.total>20)  #if included, no feasible solution exists
m.Equation(m.x<9)
m.Equation(m.y<9)
m.Maximize(m.total)
m.options.SOLVER=3
try:
   m.solve()
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception',e)
    
print('APPINFO', m.options.APPINFO)
print('APPSTATUS', m.options.APPSTATUS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `debug=False` to not raise an exception when Gekko fails to solve. When there is an exception, the results are not loaded back into `m.options`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m=GEKKO(remote=False)

m.x=m.Var()
m.y=m.Var()

m.total=m.Intermediate(m.x+m.y)

m.Equation(m.total>20)  #if included, no feasible solution exists
m.Equation(m.x<9)
m.Equation(m.y<9)
m.Maximize(m.total)
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.solve(debug=False)
    
print('APPINFO', m.options.APPINFO)
print('APPSTATUS', m.options.APPSTATUS)
```

This produces the correct error response:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :  0.0156 sec
 Objective      :  -18.023281704731964
 Unsuccessful with error code  0
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
 Creating file: infeasibilities.txt
 Use command apm_get(server,app,'infeasibilities.txt') to retrieve file
 @error: Solution Not Found

APPINFO 2
APPSTATUS 0
```